# Android . Shall I use fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I cant understand real uses of fragment . I want to create an application for notes. Is there a need to use fragments? And if an app uses fragments users under Android 3.0 cant use that app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fragments were added with 3.0, but there is the Support Library that backports them to api 7 (2.1).  So long as you use the support library fragments (which work on all versions) you can use them on 7 and up.  Although its probably becoming less and less worth your time to support anything before 4.0 these days.

You don't have to use fragments.  If they don't make sense for your app, you shouldn't.  The point of fragments is to make subactivities-  pieces of UI and related controller objects that can be combined in different ways within an Activity.  One reason to do this is to have radically different layouts in portrait and landscape, or between screen sizes, without needing separate versions.  Another is to page in and out parts of a UI.  A third is to have a little more control over the behavior of the task stack.  If you need any of these, fragments will make your life easier.  If you don't, they'll cost you time and complicate your code.  If you aren't sure, I'd start without them, converting an Activity to a Fragment later generally isn't too bad-  a few hours to a day.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to learn to use Fragment. Because

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

With fragment,you can save a lot of code and your app can work well on different devices.For the devices under Android 3.0,there is a Fragment in support library which make the new api can be used in the lower version Android.

> Static library support version of the framework's Fragment. Used to write apps that run on platforms prior to Android 3.0. When running on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still used; it does not try to switch to the framework's implementation. See the framework Fragment documentation for a class overview.

You should check more official document about [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and the support library version [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) and you will get a lot.